# Format partitions on nexus 5 after installing Ubuntu touch

Tags: partitioning, ubuntu-touch, android, format

I tried Ubuntu touch using ubports installation program on my nexus 5. That was interesting but I need to reinstall Android, which I did. But apparently I have two partitions on my phone because I have less than half of the memory I'm supposed to have on the freshly new Android install (12.5Go).

Can someone know, how to format the partitions and merger them into one? I have no problem to install Android, I just want to recover the full memory capacity (32Go). I want to completely remove Ubuntu touch from this phone.

I'm using adb on Ubuntu 18.04.

[I'm talking about mobile phones not computers: I know how to format a hard drive on Ubuntu-desktop.]

Comment: I want to remove ubuntu touch actually.

Answer (score 1):

In order to resize the Android partition of your mobile device, basically, these are the steps you'll need to follow:

1. Connect your Android device to your PC.
2. Open a terminal.

   2a. Reboot into recovery mode. (optional, depends on the partition you plan to modify)
3. Use adb to connect to your device.
4. Launch GParted (`sudo apt install gparted`) partition editor.
5. [Resize](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/) the Android partition.
6. Reinstall any required system files in case you've deleted those and afterwards you may exit the shell and reboot your device.

<sub>**Source:** adapted from [How to: repartition your Android tablet or smartphone? (all options included: change size, FS type, etc.)](https://iwf1.com/how-to-re-partition-your-android-tablet-or-smartphone-all-options-included-change-size-fs-type-etc)</sub>

Comment: With you around, the only thing that's left for me is to upvote your answers instead of answering myself!  **;-)**

Comment: **:D :D :D** I actually beat you to an answer???  **;-)**